# Unable to connect Cognos 10.2.1 from java

Tags: java, cognos-10, cognos-bi, openpages

I'm trying to connect cognos 10.2.1 from Java and fetch a report.  I get the below error. This is not happening everytime i run the java code.
log also says that the java code trying to fetch cognos port is throwing error. Someone please help!

```
faultCode: Client
 faultSubcode: 
 faultString: CM-REQ-4342 An error occurred with the client.
 faultActor: 
 faultNode: 
 faultDetail: 
{http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/bibus/3/}exception: 
<severity>error</severity>
<errorCode>caf</errorCode>
<ns1:message>
<messageString>CM-CAM-4005 Unable to authenticate. Check your security directory server connection and confirm the credentials entered at login.</messageString>
<detail>
<exception xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="bus:CAMException">
<severity xsi:type="bus:severityEnum">error</severity>
<errorCode>-38</errorCode>
<errorCodeString xml:space="preserve" xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" xsi:type="xsd:string">camAuthUnrecoverable</errorCodeString>
<messages soapenc:arrayType="bus:message[1]" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array">
<item xsi:type="bus:message">
<messageString xml:space="preserve" xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" xsi:type="xsd:string">com.openpages.security.auth.AuthenticationException: 500:Login failed with response 500</messageString>
</item>
</messages>
<promptInfo xsi:type="bus:promptInfo">
<captions soapenc:arrayType="xsd:string[1]" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array">
   <item xml:space="preserve" xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"       xsi:type="xsd:string">com.openpages.security.auth.AuthenticationException: 500:Login failed with response 500</item>
   </captions>
   </promptInfo>
   </exception>
   </detail>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly self-explanatory. You need to authenticate against your namespace, or enable anonymous access.